# Makefile:110: recipe for target 'srtp/srtp.o' failed while setting up libsrtp

Tags: 18.04, compiling

i am following the given steps to install janus gateway from here -< https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/tree/v0.6.0

here i need the library called libsrtp
i followed the same steps as given here

```
wget https://github.com/cisco/libsrtp/archive/v1.5.4.tar.gz
tar xfv v1.5.4.tar.gz
cd libsrtp-1.5.4
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-openssl
make shared_library && sudo make install
```

i am getting error on the last line ->

```
make shared_library && sudo make install
```

here is the error

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Icrypto/include -I./include -I./crypto/include -fPIC  -fPIC -Wall -O4 -fexpensive-optimizations -funroll-loops  -c srtp/srtp.c -o srtp/srtp.o
In file included from crypto/include/prng.h:53:0,
                 from crypto/include/crypto_kernel.h:50,
                 from ./include/srtp_priv.h:58,
                 from srtp/srtp.c:46:
crypto/include/aes_icm_ossl.h:75:20: error: field ‘ctx’ has incomplete type
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
                    ^~~
In file included from srtp/srtp.c:50:0:
crypto/include/aes_gcm_ossl.h:58:18: error: field ‘ctx’ has incomplete type
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
                  ^~~
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'srtp/srtp.o' failed
make: *** [srtp/srtp.o] Error 1
```

i am using ubuntu 18.04 lts

Comment: One thing, have you made sure you have all the dependencies? `sudo apt build-dep janus` (you have to enable source code in your sources through software center or by uncommenting the `src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` before you install.

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518843/error-field-ctx-has-incomplete-type-evp-cipher-ctx), you either need to downgrade OpenSSL (not easy) or try a newer version of libstrp ([looks like v2.1.0+](https://github.com/cisco/libsrtp/issues/394))